# Post a data to datatable Javascript in Django App

Tags: javascript, jquery, python, django, datatables

I have a table with jQuery and it's datatable from datatables.net. There is a field for filtering a table. How can I send a data request to this table form other view?

When I have an empty field to fill and a button, which redirect me to the view with this table, and the field for filtering will be filled by this data - sent from previous field/view.

Anyone can help me with that?

Edit: Updated my code.

my code:

base_cv.html

```
{% block css %}
    {{ block.super }}

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
{% endblock %}
{% block base %}
<div class="vvv">
    <h2>Users Base</h2><hr>
    <table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Nr.</th>
            <th>Full Name</th>
            <th>Specialization</th>     
            <th>Main language</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
          </tr>
         </thead>
         <tbody>
          {% for cv in cvs %}
              <tr>
                <td>{{forloop.counter}}.</td>
                <td><a href="{% url "proj.views.cv_detail" pk=cv.pk %}">{{cv.name}} {{cv.surname}}</a></td>
                <td>{{cv.specialization}}</td>

                {% if cv.main_programming_language %}   
                    <td>{{cv.main_programming_language}}</td>
                {% else %}
                    <td> </td>
                {% endif %}

                <td>{{ cv.age }} </td>
                <td>{{cv.email}}</td>
              </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
    </table><br>


</div>
{% endblock %}





{% block javascript %}

{{ block.super }} <!-- This makes sure the script form base.html are loaded. It's almost like supeerclassing -->

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#example').DataTable();
      });
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

groups.html:

```
<br>
                <span class="desc2">Groups description:</span>
                <p id="desc">{{g.description}}</p><br>
                {{ forma|crispy }}
                <button style="float: left" type="submit" name = "search"  value = "" class="save btn btn-default">Search by tag</button>
                     <br><br><br>
                        <button style="float: left" type="submit" name = "leave"  value = "{{g.name}}" class="save btn btn-default">Leave</button>

                        <button style="float: right" type="submit" name = "delete"  value = "{{g.name}}" class="save btn btn-default">Delete</button>

              </form>
              <br><br>

                </div>
                </div>
```

views.py:

```
@login_required
def base_cv(request):

    con = {'cvs': Cv.objects.all()}
    return render(request, 'base_cv.html', con)







@login_required
def groups(request):
user = request.user

elif request.method == "POST" and 'search' in request.POST:

    forma = SearchForm(request.POST)

    if forma.is_valid():
        search = forma.cleaned_data.get("search")

    context = {

        'search': search,

        }

    return render(request, 'base_cv.html', context)



else:                               
    cvs = Cv.objects.all()
    cv = Cv.objects.filter(author = request.user)
    per = Person.objects.all()
    gr = Group.objects.filter(members__name=request.user)
    perr = Person.objects.filter(name=request.user)
    mem = Membership.objects.filter(group = gr, person = perr)
    mem2 = Membership.objects.filter(group = gr, person = perr)
    forma = SearchForm()

    form = GroupForm()


    context = {
        'gr': gr,
        'per':per,
        'mem':mem,
        'form': form,
        'cvs':cvs,
        'cv':cv,
        'forma':forma,

    }

    return render(request, 'groups.html', context)
```

Comment: what's the other view? where is the form? where is the button?

Comment: Ok, i updated, i uploaded all important things. I Have field in groups.html and button which redirect me to the base_cv.html with context. In in context i put (i think it's correctly) the tag which should be sending off to the field flirting in base_cv.html

Comment: I am having trouble understanding your question. Can you reword it?

Comment: I found some code in JS which can accepts strings to the search() method in the table. It looks like this: 

<script src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
     <script>
       $(document).ready(function() {
         var table = $('#example').DataTable();

         $('#myInput').on( 'keyup', function() {
          table.search( this.value ).draw();
         });

       });
 </script>

.And now i dont know how to put my context from other view to this method/script.